# Trying to negate a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i am writing some scopes in rails 3 and got stuck on one. i have this scope.

scope :current, lambda {
    joins("join rents on rents.property_id = properties.id").
    where("rents.start_date <= ?  and rents.end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today)
  }

I want to be able to write a scope that gets everything BUT current. 
so something like=  Everything - current.

in console i can do something like Property.all - Property.current and it works. but i cant seem to get the syntax for the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in the console (or a controller for that matter) because you are working on arrays there.
I'm also interested in add/sub scopes from scopes.